# Check mysql if date is between dates

Tags: php, mysql

i'm learning php at the moment and i wanted to make a car hire system to challenge myself a bit.

Now i am stuck with a validation question, i got 5 diffrent cars and want to check if the car is available at the dates the user submitted.

my database table got a startdate, enddate, car and a id

This is what i'm trying to get working:

```
if($_POST){


$date1 = $_POST["startdate"];
$date2 = $_POST["enddate"];
$car= $_POST["car"];

$qry1 = "SELECT * FROM hire WHERE startdate between '{$date1}' and '{$date2}'
UNION
SELECT * FROM hire WHERE enddate between '{$date1}' and '{$date2}'";

$qry2 = "SELECT * from hire WHERE car = '{$car}'";

$results = mysql_query($qry1, $bd);
$results2 = mysql_query($qry2, $bd);
$row  = mysql_num_rows($results);
$row2  = mysql_num_rows($results2);

if ($row && $row2 > 1 ){
   die("it twerks");
}

else {
  //do stuff\
}
}
```

now it says its always available.

EDIT

start and enddate are DATE fields format is Y-m-d.

Comment: Firstly, if you're learning PHP you should learn by using PDO of MySQLi instead of MySQL as it's deprecated. What field types are `startdate` and `enddate`? The way you're querying they will need to be DATE fields, if they aren't you will need to wrap the field name in `DATE()` to make them into date fields. Also, what format are your start and end dates coming in through the post variable? Finally, your if statement needs >1 on both variables e.g. `if($row > 1 && $row2 > 1) {` (keep in mind this is saying if there is **two or more rows** from each query, then...

Comment: thx for your comment, i wil look into MySQLi i already tried it but didnt use it dont really know why, the end and start dates field name are DATE fields (will edit this). the format is Y-m-d, your comment breaks after "then...." cant see the rest.

Comment: You're right, how strange. Basically - make sure those if conditions are what you want. Do you want two or more rows or simply one or more rows (>0)?

Comment: think i want two rows one to check the car and the other one to check te date and then combine it to check if the car is available at the date what a user fills in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Sorry for the late response. I have done something similar but for a bed and breakfast, Room reservation system.

Please kindly start by normalizing your database properly.

you can have three tables such as Car, Hire, or Person.
your car table, can have all the description of your vehicle. 
Person table can have all the description of the person hiring the car. 
your hire table will reference the car_id and person_id. It will also have you start_date and end_date.
So like this.

- **car table.**

car_id (primary key),
car_color (text),
Car_make(text)

**

- **Person table**

**
person_id (primary key)
person_name (text)
person_telephone  (text)

**Hire table**
Hire_Id(auto_increment)
person_id (foreign key)
car_id (foreign key)
start_date (date)
end_date (date)

$Query="SELECT r.*
FROM car r
WHERE r.car_id NOT IN (
select b.car_id 
from hire b
where NOT (b.end_date< '2014-08-15' or b.start_date>'2014-08-12'))
order by r.car_id;"

This return all available cars

Answer (score 0):

First you want to consolidate all of your query logic to find overlapping reservations into one query *without* unions. The below should return available cars for the specified date range.

```
SELECT *
FROM hire
WHERE
  startdate  NOT BETWEEN '{$date1}' AND '{$date2}' OR
  enddate    NOT BETWEEN '{$date1}' AND '{$date2}' OR
  '{$date1}' NOT BETWEEN startdate  AND enddate    OR
  '{$date2}' NOT BETWEEN startdate  AND enddate
```

Second, you cannot take shortcuts with logic statements like this:

```
if ( $row && $row2 > 1 )
```

It must be written like:

```
if ( $row > 1 && $row2 > 1 )
```

Third, *yadda yadda* don't use `mysql_*()` functions. [See the pedantry in the comments on your question.]

I recommend PDO. It supports more database systems than just mySQL, and MySQLi has some really strange syntax.

Comment: thanks for your comment, it stills says its always available though.

Answer (score -1):

You can also directly use MySQL comparison functions on DATETIME columns: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between